# How do I add to an Array List (whose elements are defined in a constructor) external to the constructor?

Tags: java, arraylist

This is how I define the constructor for the Array List.

```
    public Quantity(String strMagnitude, String multiplier, String unit,
                    String strType)
{
        this.setMagnitude(strMagnitude);
        this.multiplier = multiplier;
        this.unit = unit;
        this.setType(strType);
    }
```

Now I want to add another element absolute magnitude to this list:

```
private static List<Quantity> getAbsoluteQuantities(List<Quantity> quantities)
    {
        List<Quantity> absoluteQuantities = new ArrayList<Quantity>();

 float absoluteMagnitude;
    // loop through quantities
    for (Quantity quantity : quantities){
        Float magnitude = quantity.getMagnitude();
        String multiplier = quantity.getMultiplier();
        String unit = quantity.getUnit();
        UnitType type = quantity.getType();

        if (multiplier != null){
            float multiplierValue = populateMultiplierFromFile().get(multiplier);
            //System.out.println(multiplierValue);
            absoluteMagnitude = magnitude * multiplierValue;
           }
        else {
            absoluteMagnitude = magnitude;
        }
            String strMagnitude = String.valueOf(absoluteMagnitude);
            String strType = String.valueOf(type);
            String originalMagnitude = String.valueOf(magnitude);
         //The line below is where I get the error
            absoluteQuantities.add(originalMagnitude, multiplier, strType, unit,strMagnitude);

    }
    return absoluteQuantities;
 }
```

}

How do I do that? I keep getting an error which tells me that I can't define a list with (String, String, String, String, String) when the format it takes is (String, String, String, String).

Comment: There's not enough information in your post to solve your problem. Consider posting a small, self contained complete example.

Comment: It's look like you putting 5 input parameters to a function that's accept only 4

Comment: Are you doing new ArrayList and not a new Quantity?

Comment: @printfmyname that's exactly my question. How do I add an additional element to this function so that it accepts 5 inputs but I can't modify this function as it is being used elsewhere as well with 4 inputs. Is my approach incorrect? I'm a beginner in Java so I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Simply make a new function with the same name but which accepts 5 arguments instead of 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line:

```
         //The line below is where I get the error
            absoluteQuantities.add(originalMagnitude, multiplier, strType, unit,strMagnitude);
```

to

```
        absoluteQuantities.add(new Quantity(originalMagnitude, multiplier, strType, unit,strMagnitude));
```

You want to add a `Quantity` instance to `List<Quantity>` and hence you should be first constructing the `Quantity` instance and then appending it to the list

**UPDATE based on response from OP**
You actually want to pass in  an  absoluteMagnitude to your `Quantity` instance which actually takes in only 4 parameters - `originalMagnitude`, `multiplier`, `unit` and `strType`.

You can do this using the below two steps :

1. Constructor chaining using overloaded constructors. In this you define an overload of the `Quantity` cosntructor that takes in 5 parameters. So your `Quantity` class has two constructors - one you defined and the other the overloaded one which takes in the `absoluteMagnitude`

   public Quantity(String strMagnitude, String multiplier, String unit,
                           String strType)
       {
           //invoke the chanined constructor with a default value for absoluteMagnitude
           this(strMagnitude, multiplier, unit, strType, "0.0");
       }

   ```
   public Quantity(String strMagnitude, String multiplier, String unit,
                       String strType, String absoluteMagnitude)
   {
       //initialize class level variabes using the parameter values
   }
   ```
2. Expose a `getter/setter` pair for the individual attributes. Hence there would also be an individual pair for the `absoluteMagnitude` attribute

   public String getAbsoluteMagnitude()
   {
      return this.absoluteMagnitude;
   }

   public void setAbsoluteMagnitude(String absoluteMagnitude)
   {
      this.absoluteMagnitude = absoluteMagnitude;
   }

Now when you want to create a `Quantity` instance without specifying an `absoluteMagnitude` value then you call the constructor that takes in 4 parameters. You can then set the `absoluteMagnitude` value at a later stage using the setter.

If you however want to specify the `absoluteMagnitude` value then use the other overloaded version of the constructor that takes in 5 parameters.

Comment: @PrahladDeshpande tried that already. Gives me this error: The constructor Quantity(String, String, String, String, String) is undefined

Comment: @PrahladDeshpanse Thanks so much! This is exactly what I was looking for!